# htaccess rewrite url with eventual subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I have urls like this:

> `https://mywonderfulsite.com/page`

and my .htaccess rewrites it as

> `https://mywonderfulsite.com/index.php?source=page`

The .htaccess is the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule \.(php)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^custom404\.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^custom500\.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?source=$1 [L]
```

This fails if the url contains a subfolder like

> `https://mywonderfuldomain.com/subfolder/anotherpage`

that should become

> `https://mywonderfuldomain.com/index.php?source=/subfolder/anotherpage`

I don't seem to get how to handle this situation. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with pattern `([^/]+)` that matches anything but a `/`.

Use it like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(?:favicon\.ico|(?:index|custom500|custom404)\.html)$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ index.php?source=$0 [L,QSA]
```